# Dissolve FeatureCollection using attribute

Tags: google-earth-engine, merge, attribute-joins, dissolve, feature-collection

I have a feature collection with a number of properties, all numbers. I want to aggregate all features in the collection that have a property in common. For instance, I want to merge features that have the same date value, and I wish to sum up the values of all other fields in the resulting feature collection.
For example, a dummy feature collection:

```
var feat_list = [
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-02', count:1}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-04', count:1}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-02', count:3}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-01', count:2})
]
```

Should become this:

```
[
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-02', count:4}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-04', count:1}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-01', count:2})
]
```

I have tried everything on planet Earth. I tried using dictionaries also, but when I try to check if a date is present in two dictionaries or not using .contains() and && operator it doesn't produce Boolean values correctly.

Comment: Sorry, not all features are numbers. One field is date too, which is string, rest all are numbers. Please find the script here https://code.earthengine.google.com/9bf96fe669b3df9a0c34e3d4604dea45

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `.distinct()` and `ee.Join.saveAll()`. It's a bit wordy, but it will be efficient for large collections, compared to other options.

```js
var collection = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-02', count:1, x:1}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-04', count:1, x:1}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-02', count:3, x:0}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(77.58, 13), {date:'2020-10-01', count:2, x:0})
]);

var propertiesToReduce = ['count', 'x'];

// We need one reducer for each property being summed.
// We could do this in a loop, but in case there is a property that *isn't*
// being summed (where you want e.g. the mean), writing it out is more flexible.
// This must have exactly as many combined reducers (or more precisely, exactly
// as many inputs) as propertiesToReduce.
var reducer = ee.Reducer.sum().setOutputs(['count'])
  .combine(ee.Reducer.sum().setOutputs(['x']));

var merged = ee.Join.saveAll('matches')
  .apply(
    collection.distinct('date'),  // We only want one date (don't care which).
    collection, ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'date', rightField: 'date'}))
  .map(function (joinFeature) {
    // Prepare a collection of all the features with the same date.
    // (ee.Join.saveAll gives us a list by default.)
    var matches = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(joinFeature.get('matches')));
    return joinFeature
      // Keep only the date property unmodified; everything else will be
      // put back via the reducer.
      .select(['date'])
      // Sum the matches' properties using reduceColumns, and add that to the
      // single feature's properties using setMulti.
      .setMulti(matches.reduceColumns(reducer, propertiesToReduce));
  });

print(merged);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c87d8fd993925712c94cb1f1821dee4a